# Keycloak error encountered after removing a client from the realm

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, keycloak, keycloak-services

This question is for KeyCloak 3.2.1.Final

I encountered an issue with a KeyCloak realm with User Federation pointing to an enterprise LDAP server.  While we were testing an application during development we added clients that pointed back to our local pcs so that we could work independently.  These each share the same User Federation configuration which contains several mappers.  Since role-ldap-mapper is specific to a client, each of us had to add a new role mapper that was specific to our client in order to get the roles we needed on the token after sign-in.

After we completed our work, we deleted one of the clients and it subsequently put the realm in a state where nobody was able to log in.  In the keycloak logs we see this repeatedly:

```
2018-01-31 14:56:19,827 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-10) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: Can't found requested client with clientId: [********]
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.mappers.membership.role.RoleLDAPStorageMapper.getTargetRoleContainer(RoleLDAPStorageMapper.java:235)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.mappers.membership.role.RoleLDAPStorageMapper$LDAPRoleMappingsUserDelegate.<init>(RoleLDAPStorageMapper.java:320)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.mappers.membership.role.RoleLDAPStorageMapper.proxy(RoleLDAPStorageMapper.java:289)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.proxy(LDAPStorageProvider.java:190)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.importUserFromLDAP(LDAPStorageProvider.java:485)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.getUserByUsername(LDAPStorageProvider.java:450)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.findOrCreateAuthenticatedUser(LDAPStorageProvider.java:714)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.authenticate(LDAPStorageProvider.java:654)
at org.keycloak.credential.UserCredentialStoreManager.authenticate(UserCredentialStoreManager.java:282)
at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:89)
at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:200)
at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:843)
at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:714)
at org.keycloak.protocol.AuthorizationEndpointBase.handleBrowserAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationEndpointBase.java:142)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildAuthorizationCodeAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:414)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.build(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:143)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor684.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:138)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:107)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:133)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:101)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We quickly realized that the problem was the role-ldap-mapper that retained that link to the client that was deleted.  Once the bad mapper was removed, everything continued to work as expected.  It would appear that having a client-specific mapper linked to a client that no longer exists is detrimental to the system.  As such, I would expect that removing the client via the UI would also remove any mappers associated with it.

I'm posting this here as a formality based on the instructions I found here: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HelpBugReport.  I plan to write up a bug report and add it to https://issues.jboss.org.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?  Can anyone confirm that this is indeed a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: For those who care: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-6465

Comment: For any who happen to land here, this ticket was closed without being fixed because I was unable to test the bug in their latest version of the software.  Beware, for here there be dragons.